# sudo on Windows 10 Linux subsystem cannot resolve local machine name

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

I installed Windows 10 Anniversary update and the Linux subsystem. When running anything with sudo it takes ages and then I get this error message:

> sudo: unable to resolve host MYMACHINE

How to get rid of this and make sudo fast?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have to edit `/etc/hosts` while superuser and add your machine name after the first line with localhost

```
127.0.0.1        localhost MYMACHINE
```

This will make the system not try to resolve the hostname from DNS.

Comment: Yup, that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also remove `/etc/hosts` and restart bash to generate a version that contains your hostname. For me, it created a line with my computer name and my fully qualified name 
`127.0.0.1   fbc-2000.domain.local fbc-2000`